# Is it possible to link a PSO Algorithm written in Python to LINGO software?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, particle-swarm

I am trying to implement a PSO Algorithm using python on certain variables that will be used in solving a quadratic program written in LINGO software. In the python code I want it to work normally except when it gets the value of the objective function it opens the LINGO software and uses the data currently available from the search space and transfer it to the quadratic model and then solve it and get the objective function value from there instead of everything being on Python. Is this possible? If so, how can I implement it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It should be possible if there is a Python API from Lingo/Lindo. All these solvers are just software tools with inputs and outputs. Not sure why the CPLEX tag is relevant though.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick I thought it was relevant as I couldn't find a tag for LINGO. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well... it worked as it found me! Not used Lindo/Lingo for a few years, but a big CPLEX user for 20+ years. Especially interested in unusual and hybrid systems and solutions that mix LP, MIP, QP etc with CP, LNS, VLNS and other heuristic and algorithmic approaches. Try also looking up topics like 'matheuristics'.